# Dynamic PathMatcher from String

Tags: scala, akka-http

I have a test server that takes expectations at runtime and responds accordingly when the expectation is called. The expectations are stored in `state`. Here's the route:

```
val route: Route = ctx => {
  val routes = state.map { case (pathString, responses) =>
    get {
      path(pathString) {
         ...
      }
    }
  }
  concat(routes: _*)(ctx)
}
```

This approach works when the expected path does not have any slashes, e.g. `foo.html`. But when it has a fuller path, e.g. `foo/bar.html`, then the directive will not match.

How can I correctly convert the given path string into a `PathMatcher`?

I have tried `pathString.split("/").foldLeft(Neutral)(_ / _)` but this caused the simple case of `foo.html` to fail.

Answer (score 3):

`PathMatchers.separateOnSlashes(String)` is provided by the library and does what I need.